# Xamarin Custom Panels: Size type missing. What references do I need?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I've been following some tutorials to learn Xamarin/Xaml.  I'm currently looking at custom panels.

My custom Panel class is currently as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

public class MyCustomPanel : Panel
{

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size size)
    {
        return base.MeasureOverride(size);
    }
}
```

With this code i get:

> The type or namespace 'Size' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Intellisense tells me (hovering over the base MeasureOverride) that the type of Size I'm looking for is ***Windows.Foundation.Size*** however I'm already using Windows.Foundation.  It does not have a type of Size.

If I try to resolve with intellsence the only Size types availble to me are System.Drawing and Xamarin.Forms.  None of these are suitable for MeasureOverride.

Can anyone help with this?  What is it that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.measureoverride have you checked this link ? as i see from here `MeasureOverride` child of `Windows.UI.Xaml`

Comment: @Halilİbrahim In my environment the namespace inline `Windows.UI.Xaml` does not have the type Panel.  Instead it looks as if it's been moved to `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`.  There is a link to Size in the page you linked that takes me to `Winows.Foundation` again.

Comment: try to remove the namespace that contains Size property inside it. then let the visual studio pop up the true namespace for you. maybe this can help

Comment: Unfortunately the Panel propery is listed only under `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` and Size can be found only under `System.Drawing` or `Xamarin.Forms`, neither of which are suitable.

Comment: There is no control called `panel` in Xamarin.forms. It's a control of `UWP`. You should customize panel under `UWP` project instead of Xamarin.forms.

Comment: @jackHua that has resolved it.  Thanks so much!